# Switch case for images

Tags: java, android

I'm going to create the app which will take random 3 numbers from array `String [] powerBalls` with 5 numbers and will switch the image with picture to every number and then show the number and picture(e.g. string "1" from array `powerballs` will have the image with the name "o1"). The problem is that on the display I get the numbers and can see the picture as long as switch case will find the correct image. Then the app shutting down. The images are all the time visible and they should appear only with the random number. What is wrong with this code? 
I have really no idea what I'm doing wrong and could not find some example for this program.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_zufallsgenerator);
    bindViews();


    mGenerateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            generateRandomNumbers();

        }
    });
}

public void generateRandomNumbers(){
    Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(powerBalls));

    mFirstNumber.setText(powerBalls[0]);
    mSecondNumber.setText(powerBalls[1]);
    mThirdNumber.setText(powerBalls[2]);
    mFourthNumber.setText(powerBalls[3]);
    mFifthNumber.setText(powerBalls[4]);
    mSixthNumber.setText(powerBalls[5]);

    switch (powerBalls[0]) {
        case "1":
            imageViewDice1.setImageResource(R.drawable.o1);
            imageViewDice1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view_dice1);
            break;
        case "2":
            imageViewDice2.setImageResource(R.drawable.o2);
            imageViewDice2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view_dice2);
            break;
        case "3":
            imageViewDice3.setImageResource(R.drawable.o3);
            imageViewDice3 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view_dice3);
            break;
        case "4":
            imageViewDice4.setImageResource(R.drawable.o4);
            imageViewDice4 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view_dice4);
            break;
        case "5":
            imageViewDice5.setImageResource(R.drawable.o5);
            imageViewDice5 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view_dice5);
            break;
        case "6":
            imageViewDice6.setImageResource(R.drawable.o6);
            imageViewDice6 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view_dice6);
            break;
    }
    switch (powerBalls[1]) {
        case "1":
            imageViewDice1.setImageResource(R.drawable.o1);
            imageViewDice1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view_dice1);
            break;
        case "2":
            imageViewDice2.setImageResource(R.drawable.o2);
            imageViewDice2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view_dice2);
            break;
        case "3":
            imageViewDice3.setImageResource(R.drawable.o3);
            imageViewDice3 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view_dice3);
            break;
        case "4":   // and so on...*****
```

and on the end of the java class:

```
public void bindViews(){
mFirstNumber = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.firstNumber);
mSecondNumber = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.secondNumber);
mThirdNumber = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.thirdNumber);
mFourthNumber = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.fourthNumber);
mFifthNumber = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.fifthNumber);
mSixthNumber = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.sixthNumber);
mPowerBall = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.powerBall);
mGenerateButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mgenerateButton);
```

The example of the xml file with views:

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/firstNumber"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:fontFamily="serif"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:text="01"
    android:textColor="@color/startblue"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Thank you in advance for your suggestions and answers. Cheers

Comment: I think the problem is that the ImageView is "on" all the time and the app shutting down if the result of the generateRandomNumbers() generate second ImageView. I have no idea how to make that ImageView will appear only after the number will be generatet...

Comment: When you say " the app shutting down", you mean you put the activity in the background, kill the app or what is the action are you doing to "shut down" the app?

Comment: @aaroncio I mean kill the app

Comment: You can put the `android:visibility="gone"` in your `ImageView` xml and in your switch cases use `imageViewDice1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`.
Also, I am not sure of your functionality but change the order of cases, `imageViewDice1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view_dice1);` should go before `imageViewDice1.setImageResource(R.drawable.o1);`.

Comment: @aaroncio thanks it works better with your advice. But now the images are staying and only numbers are changing and the idea was that every push of the button will generate new random numbers with images.

Comment: The problem already solved, thanks aaroncio for your tipp with setVisibility!